# Video Player always stay at the top in Cocos Creator?

Tags: cocoscreator

I am developing a game where I want my textured image to remain on the top of video player but currently video player always stays on the top of all views? 
I am using the CocosCreator framework and typescript.

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

**VideoPlayer**, **EditBox** and **WebView** Component are appended in **cc.game.container** so these component will add as last child and These will appear on the top.

By following these steps you can change the order or appearance.

1. If you wan to put something like a video player Behind the canvas and want to
   put other component above it, So first you will have to make your canvas transparent. You can do this by setting the flag of engine file "***/engine/cocos2d/core/platform/CCMacro.js***"

[Change the flag  ENABLE_TRANSPARENT_CANVAS to true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JMyx.png)

2. You need the change the ZOrder of canvas and video component class in the start of the script responsible for video player.

```js
           start: function () { 
            cc.director.setClearColor(new cc.Color(0, 0, 0, 0))
            let videoElement = document.getElementsByClassName('cocosVideo')[0];
            videoElement.style.zIndex = 2;
            let gameCanvas = document.getElementsByClassName('gameCanvas')[0];
            gameCanvas.style.position = 'relative';
            gCanvas.style.zIndex = 4;
       },
```

3.Here is the complete script to play a video over canvas.

```js
cc.Class({
    extends: cc.Component,

    properties: {
        video:{
            default: null,
            type: cc.VideoPlayer
        }
    },

    // use this for initialization
    onLoad: function () {
        this.videoPlayer = this.node.getComponent(cc.VideoPlayer);
        this.videoPlayer.node.on('ready-to-play', this.callback, this);
    },
    
    start: function () { 
        cc.director.setClearColor(new cc.Color(0, 0, 0, 0))
        let videoElement = document.getElementsByClassName('cocosVideo')[0];
        videoElement.style.zIndex = 2;
    
        let gameCanvas = document.getElementsByClassName('gameCanvas')[0];
        gameCanvas.style.position = 'relative';
        gCanvas.style.zIndex = 4;
    },

    callback () {
        console.log("video ready to play")
        this.videoPlayer.play();
     },

    // called every frame
    update: function (dt) {

    },
});
```